# Why does $\sum_{2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(x\ln(x)^3)}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus

I did the integral test but I keep getting the series diverges.

I solve this problem by u-substitution subbing for $\ln(x)$ :

$u=\ln(x)$

$du=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Did you make sure it follows all the rules for the integral test? Continuous, positive, and decreasing?

Comment: Yes it is continuous, positive, and decreasing.

Comment: After your substitution don't you get integral of $1/u^3$ from $2$ to $\infty$? If so that integral converges...

Comment: Can use Cauchy's Condensation Test.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *Bertrand's series*, $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 2}\dfrac1{n^{\alpha}\ln^\beta n} $.

It is standard these series converge if and only if $\alpha>1$ (by comparison with a *Riemann series*) or $\alpha=1$ **and** $\beta>1$ (integral test).

Indeed $\displaystyle\int_2^\infty\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x}{x\ln^\beta x}=\int_{\ln2}^\infty\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu u }{u^\beta}=-\frac1{(\beta-1)u^{\beta-1}}\biggr\rvert_{\ln2}^\infty=\frac1{(\ln2)^{\beta-1}}.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $n \ln n^3=3n\ln n$ and $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ diverge we have that $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n\ln n^3}$ diverge.

Comment: It's $\ln(n)^3$ not $\ln(n^3)$.

Comment: Well there's no need to down vote, as the notation is quite bad.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Use comparison test

$$\frac{1}{n \ln(n)^3} <\frac{1}{n \ln(n)^2} $$

Or observe that $\int\frac{1}{x \ln(x)^3}dx=-\frac{1}{2\ln(x)^2}+C$